# JQuery Tablesorter won't sort MySQL PHP table that is loaded by a session script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, tablesorter

I'm trying to add a JQuery Tablesorter and have it sort a table that is PHP and loaded from a script that is outside of the display page. I have it to where the data goes into the table correctly and the column headers are clickable but when I click on the header the data doesn't sort. Here is the code to the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$results = $_SESSION['results'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Welcome | Mountain and Alpine Loan Centers</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Mountain and Alpine Loan Centers">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablesorter/themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#test").tablesorter();
         });
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div align="center">
        <img src="../img/Logo4_White_Black.jpg" height="126" width="266">
        <nav id="nav01"></nav></div>
        <div align="center"><br><br><br>
        </div>

            <?php
            if($results) {
    echo "<table id='test' class='tablesorter' border='2'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='header'># of Records</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Date Set</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Branch</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Appointment Date</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Employee</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>First Name</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Last Name</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Last Four</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Phone</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>City</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>State</th>";
    echo "<th class='header'>Zip</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";


            foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $result) {

                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$result['rows']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['set_date']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['branch']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['appt_date']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['employee']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['fname']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['lname']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['last_four']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['phone']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['city']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['state']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$result['zip']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</tbody>";

            }


}else{

    echo "No Records Found";
}
?>
</div>           

            <div align="center">
            <p>Return to the<a href="test.php">Test Page</a></p>
            </div>


        <script src="js/jquery-latest.min.map"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-latest.min.map"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, jQuery is clent-side. Do you have *any* errors in the console?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard There are no error in the console. The data populates the table correctly just won't sort the data when I click on the header.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure I can replicate this on jsFiddle. The data comes from the MySQL database depending on what is entered onto a form. I tried to put this on jsFiddle but it didn't work. You can see this form and then the next page by going here: [link](http://alcmlcinc.com/test.php)

Comment: I found your errors and posted an answer below.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  
I just tried this and it still won't sort data when I click on the column headers. Please feel free to look at this page here [link](http://alcmlcinc.com/test.php) use the 'Employee' name 'Brittany' and the date range July 1 - July 3. You will go tot the results page with data to see what's going on. Still won't sort even after making the changes you suggested.

Comment: There is only one record for that time period @Derek. Eliminating the employee name I get 443 records back and they sort just as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a `<tbody>` for each row instead of for the overall table:

```
<?php
if($results) {
echo "<table id='test' class='tablesorter' border='2'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class='header'># of Records</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Date Set</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Branch</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Appointment Date</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Employee</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>First Name</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Last Name</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Last Four</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Phone</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>City</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>State</th>";
echo "<th class='header'>Zip</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $result) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$result['rows']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['set_date']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['branch']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['appt_date']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['employee']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['fname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['lname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['last_four']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['phone']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['city']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['state']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$result['zip']}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
}
```

In addition you do not have a closing `</table>` tag.

To fix you need to remove the lines adding `tbody` to each row. Then add an opening `tbody` to your first PHP block before you start the loop. Once the loop is done close `tbody` and `table` outside of the `foreach` statement.

Comment: I just tried this and it still won't sort data when I click on the column headers. Please feel free to look at this page here [link](http://alcmlcinc.com/test.php) use the 'Employee' name 'Brittany' and the date range July 1 - July 3

Comment: Nevermind... It did work. I forgot to remove the </tbody> out of the loop. Thanks so much for your help. Works like a champ

Comment: I clicked the checkmark for your answer. Thanks again for your help with this